# google map refuse to show

Tags: android, api, google-maps, console

I just created a new project and I added API Key, 
When I try to run the project google maps won't load

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mapproblem.zakaria.maptestprobleme.MapsActivity" />



public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                           Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                           Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                            API Key: AIzaSgYrFTjKL2hp0SLKaTd_-1rVdwxOQy1VDu0
                            Android Application (;): 55:FA:14:99:28:28:D7:43:0F:19:62:E4:10:7C:7A:67:8F:AA:10:6C;com.mapproblem.zakaria.maptestprobleme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding key won't be enough. You need to enable Maps Android API as suggested by error.

Open [Google Cloud platform](https://console.cloud.google.com), select your project and then go to "API and Services" > Library. Search for Maps SDK for Android and enable it.

This should fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should Go to your  [google developer console](http://console.developers.google.com) and enable google map api for your project and on top toolbar choose your project, then in dashboard section choose `Enabled APIs and services`, search for Google Map Api then enable it

Comment: how can I do that.